# Menu to choose application

Tags: android, menu

On my phone sometimes when i try to make a particular action, a menu shows up, and ask me to choose between different installed applications that could perform that action,  like for example when i try to make a call, that menu gives me the choice between 'Call', 'Skype' and 'Viber'.

what do we call this type of menus?

I'm working on an application, and i want that when i click on an imageView the menu shows up, and give me the choice to select a source for that imageView, either from gallery or take a new image using Camera.

is it possible to use this type of menus in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an Intent chooser.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-text-content

> If there's an installed application with a filter that matches
>   ACTION_SEND and MIME type text/plain, the Android system will run it;
>   if more than one application matches, the system displays a
>   **disambiguation dialog (a "chooser")** that allows the user to choose an
>   app.

In case you want to use it with Camera or Gallery, 1 minute of search would have let you get those answers:

[Dialog to pick image from gallery or from camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165302/dialog-to-pick-image-from-gallery-or-from-camera)

[Allow user to select camera or gallery for image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455558/allow-user-to-select-camera-or-gallery-for-image)

[Android How can I call Camera or Gallery Intent Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732872/android-how-can-i-call-camera-or-gallery-intent-together)