# Android how can I pick image from camera or gallery at the same time with one Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

Here's a implementation I found in a app named `Pawoo`. I can choose take photo or pick a image from system built-in gallery or third-party gallery at the same time.

I wonder how to achieve it with just one Intent. Because it seems not implements by third-party library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I already know how to achieve it. Inspired by [Intent to choose between the camera or the gallery in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524617/intent-to-choose-between-the-camera-or-the-gallery-in-android/)

The answer of qustion is not just one Intent. Simply, in my question screentshot, there's 3 actions, that's means 3 Intents. The key method is `Intent.createChooser()`

Here's my complete code:

```
public void click(View view) {
        File file = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        Uri cameraOutputUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = getPickIntent(cameraOutputUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, -1);
    }

    private Intent getPickIntent(Uri cameraOutputUri) {
        final List<Intent> intents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

        if (true) {
            intents.add(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
        }

        if (true) {
            setCameraIntents(intents, cameraOutputUri);
        }

        if (intents.isEmpty()) return null;
        Intent result = Intent.createChooser(intents.remove(0), null);
        if (!intents.isEmpty()) {
            result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
        }
        return result;


    }

    private void setCameraIntents(List<Intent> cameraIntents, Uri output) {
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }
    }
```

Here's the my demo:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not one `Intent`. This dialog is a [bottom sheet](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/).