# Android How can trim video captured from phone camera or from gallery

Tags: android, video-capture, android-gallery, android-camera-intent, trim

Is it possible to call an intent for taking video through phone camera or gallery together. I don't want to choose an option for this like from camera, from gallery etc. And also i have to apply trimming for the video taken.
I have the following 2 requirements:
1. First of all, I need to call the gallery and camera intent together.because I need to take video both from phone camera and from gallery in single frame.
2. I need to trim the video taken in 5/6 frame.
Can someone help me find the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How can I call Camera or Gallery Intent Together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732872/android-how-can-i-call-camera-or-gallery-intent-together)

Comment: My question is different.its about to call intent for taking videos